# jquery .live() function only works once

Tags: jquery

When I run this code it performs as it should the first time however when I try the action a second time nothing happens. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$('.delete_user').live("click",function(){
var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    var $form = $('#member_search').serialize();
        $.post("server_code.php",{id: $id, form: $form},
            function(data){ 
            $('#member_row_container').html(data).show();
            $('.row_standard:odd').addClass('row_alternate');
        });
    $(".div_alert").hide();  
    $(".overlay").hide();
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: please set up working example on jsfiddle, so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Should anything happen? Can you delete a user more than once?

Comment: $(this).attr('id') - this.id please

Comment: @redsquare ;) It's one of those, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's entirely related to this, but you were sending data in the wrong format. Try this:

```
$('.delete_user').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#member_search').serialize(),
        data = 'id='+this.id+'&'+form;
    $.post('server_code.php', data, function(html){ 
        $('#member_row_container').html(html).show();
        $('.row_standard:odd').addClass('row_alternate');
    }, 'html');
    $(".div_alert").hide();  
    $(".overlay").hide();
});
```

Comment: data is just fine being sent as an object, gets automatically encoded as well this way ..

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: It will be encoded as `id=123&form=field1%3DValue%2B1%26field2%3DValue%2B2%26field2%3DValue%2B2`.

Comment: ahhh.. you mean that the form data will be put under a single field named `form`.. You got a point there, although i am not sure what the OP is trying to achieve..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I found out why it wasn't working. When I was calling back the server code the code in the php was incorrect. It was a pretty stupid mistake and I was looking in all the wrong places. Thanks again :)

Comment: @user: Glad you got it resolved. Either post your solution to this question, or accept my answer by clicking on the empty tick below the vote counts on the top left side of the it. So, this question gets marked as resolved.